# Custom Permalink

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules, 404-error

I am trying to make my website so that `example.com/profile/?name=john` can be accessed in a cleaner URL such as `example.com/profile/john/`.

I have it working so I can access `$_GET["name"]` but it shows me a `404` page. My permalink is set to `/%postname%/` and I just need to access the profile name by using `$_GET`. The profile name is not related to WordPress like an author.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without returning a `404` page and if so, how it could be done. My current `.htaccess` code is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/$ /profile/?name=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What is that URL for? How do you generate that permastruct in the PHP side?

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The custom rule you are trying doesn't meet the criteria. Here's a nifty [online `.htaccess` tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) tool to see to check rewrite logic.

Use the follow `RewriteRule` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Be sure to replace `^example\.com$` on the first line with your actual domain.

You can also embed it in the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag that was created by WordPress, which should look like the following as the end result:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# BEGIN Custom Rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile/%2/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END Custom Rules
# END WordPress
```